# FB iOS SDK with UITabBarController as root controller in app delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios4, fbconnect

I instanced a UITabBarController as the root controller for my app delegate.  For FB IOs SDK it says to do the following inside of:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

"In this method, call your application's Facebook object's handleOpenURL method, making sure to pass in the url parameter."

Is the standard way to use FB ios sdk with a tab bar controller to subclass UITabBarController and create the FB object there?  Or is there another way where i don't have to subclass uitab bar controller and create the fb object else where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to subclass `UITabBarController`. There isn't a standard place to create the `Facebook` object. You can create it anywhere you'd like. It depends on your application. Check out [AcaniWelcome](https://github.com/acani/AcaniWelcome). It creates the `Facebook` object in the [`FacebookUser : ManagedObject` `loadSession` instance method](https://github.com/acani/AcaniWelcome/blob/master/Models/FacebookUser.m#L47-53).

Answer (score 0):

you can use fb ios sdk as you want. You don't need to subclass UITabBarController.